# Oracle query that count connections by minute with start and end times provided

Tags: oracle

I have connections into a system and in the database I have the username, starttime_of_connection, and endtime_of_connection.  I want to be able to check by minute, how many connections were active at each minute.  This is using Oracle DB.  Any suggestions or help?

Comment: Are you looking within a range, e.g. each minute for a given date? Do you already have a source that gives you each minute in your range? If you've already tried anything, please show what you have so far.

Comment: It would be within a range, yes, for a month for example.  I do not have a source which gives each minute I only have start and end times for each connection and the name of the person connecting.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `starttime_of_connection` and `endtime_of_connection` are date or timestamp columns, you can do something like this.  I'm dynamically generating dates with every minute today in the `each_minute` common table expression (CTE).  You can extend this to generate dates across multiple days or to substitute in some other table that you already have that gives you the data for each minute.

```
WITH each_minute AS (
  SELECT trunc(sysdate) + numtodsinterval( level, 'minute' ) dt
    FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= 24*60
)
SELECT em.dt, count(*) num_active_connections
  FROM each_minute em
       LEFT OUTER JOIN your_table yt
         ON( em.dt BETWEEN yt.starttime_of_connection AND yt.endtime_of_connection )
```

I'm also assuming that `endtime_of_connection` is always populated-- you may use a NULL `endtime_of_connection` to indicate a connection that has not yet ended in which case your join would be something like

```
ON(    em.dt BETWEEN yt.starttime_of_connection AND yt.endtime_of_connection
    OR (em.dt >= yt.starttime_of_connection AND yt.endtime_of_connection IS NULL) )
```

Comment: So far this has worked better than anything I have created - but I need it for the month, and not just a day.  I am also not seeing every minute regardless of a connection - any additional help for that since so far you have gotten me WAY further than I had

Comment: @pcscbr- If you don't want rows to be returned where the `count(*)` is 0, do an `inner join` rather than a `left outer join`.  I'm not sure what you mean by "need it for the month".  If you want one row per month, you can change the `each_minute` query to return one row per month rather than one row per minute.

Answer (score 0):

This query worked for me:

```
with period as (select date '2015-04-01' d1, 
                       date '2015-04-30' + 1 - interval '1' minute d2 from dual),
tmp as (
  select d1, d2, trunc(starttime_of_connection, 'mi') soc, 
      trunc(nvl(endtime_of_connection, greatest(starttime_of_connection, d2)), 'mi') eoc
    from connections, period),
cn as (select greatest(soc, d1) cd1, least(eoc, d2) cd2 
    from tmp where soc<=d2 and eoc>=d1),
mt as (select d1 + (level-1)/(24*60) m 
    from period connect by d1 + (level-1)/(24*60) <= d2)
select to_char(m, 'mm-dd hh24:mi') minute, count(cd1) cnt 
  from mt /*left*/ join cn on m between cd1 and cd2
  group by m order by m
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8146/1)

In first line please change dates for analyzed period. If you want to show minutes with no connections, for instance to make graph then change `join` at bottom to `left join`.
For big number of connections and long period query may execute very long. If so you can divide period to weekends/days and union results.

Subquery `tmp` truncates dates to minutes and fills endtime of connections for null values. 
`cn` filters previous results to interesting period. `mt` is hierarchical minute generator. 
Main query joins connections `cn` and minutes `mt`, groups them and orders by time.

If there was connection which started at hour 23:34:07 and ended at 23:34:45 it is counted for minute 23:34.